# Every graph G with at least one edge has a subgraph H with $\delta(H) > \varepsilon(H) \geqslant \varepsilon(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to know how to proof (or any other alternative proof) and understanding the intuition  of this proposition, it it taken from textbook "Graph Theory" by Reinhard Diestel, P.5 Proposition 1.2.2.  [Book](http://www.esi2.us.es/~mbilbao/pdffiles/DiestelGT.pdf)

the Proposition is as following 
[image]

the first thing I try is to follow the condition [$\delta(H) > \varepsilon(H) \geqslant \varepsilon(G)$] by taking an example say $K_5$

[image]

Now, suppose I take two nodes to be subgraph of $K_5$, then the subgraph would be $K_2$

[image]

If I just follow the previous condition

$$\delta(H) = 1 > \varepsilon(H) = |E|/|V| = 1/2 = 0.5 \geqslant \varepsilon(G) = |E|/|V| = 10/5 = 2$$

It does not come as desired, so I know there is something wrong with my understanding of this formula but I can not see it clearly

even the proof is not clear for me, in case there is an alternative proof would be very helpful ..

the proof is as following

[image]

i.e. he states that try to delete the nodes of small degree one by one until only nodes of large degree remain. Now if the case is we have equal degree of all nodes, then does that mean we need to delete or not? (Equal degree happens on case of complete graph).

$\varepsilon(H)$ is the ratio of the edges and nodes $|E|/|V|$

$\delta(H)$ is the minimum degree of all subgraph

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that he asserts only the existence of such a subgraph. He does not state that every subgraph must fulfill this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it says here is that there **exists** at least one subgraph $H$ with $\delta(H)> \epsilon (H)\ge \epsilon(G) $. It is not true that every subgraph $H$ meets this condition.

In this case the only subgraph $H$ that meets the condition is $H=G$, so $\delta(H)=4$, $\epsilon (H)=2$, $\epsilon (G)=2$. Thus $\delta(H)>\epsilon (H)\ge\epsilon (G)$.

Comment: Aha, Thank you so much .. (notice that $\delta(H)$=4, not $5$)

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out!